# Is the concept of abstraction relevant to tables in MySQL? If so, how can I do it?

Tags: mysql, oop, abstraction

I want to store data on various engines in a MySQL database, which includes both piston and rotary engines.

---

In OO languages, I can create and extend an `Engine` superclass to obtain `PistonEngine` and `RotaryEngine` subclasses.

The `PistonEngine` subclass would contain properties such as *CylinderNo*, *PistonBore* and *PistonStroke*.

The `RotaryEngine` subclass would contain properties like *RotorThickness* and *RotorDiameter*.

---

In MySQL, while I can create two separate tables for piston and rotary engines respectively, I would prefer to maintain an *EngineType* field as part of the engine data, and store all data common to both engine types in a single table.

How can I design my database to avoid data redundancy as much as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create four tables in this situation.

One called EngineTypes which would just have the id/value pairs for your engine types
1 Rotary
2 Piston

One called Engines that contains the information that is relevant to both piston and rotary engines. It would have a column in it that contains the engine type id.

One table called RotaryEngineDetails that contains all your rotary engine specific data. It would have a foreign key to your engines table.

One table called PistonEngineDetails that contains all your piston engine specific data..

Comment: Yes it would map to an enum where you explicitly set the values to the ID's in your EngineTypes table.

Comment: @OG: I quite like your table design suggestion. It's lean and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to create a single table with all of the information needed for both engine types, including a key for the engine type itself.  After that you could create a view for each type of engine "classes" so it would appear to be its own object.  Although, depending on all of the data that you are storing, it may not make since as your structure would not be normalized.

**Update**
Based on comment, I have expanded my answer.

By definition, view is a virtual or logical table which is composed of result set of a SELECT query. Because view is like the table which consists of row and column so you can retrieve and update data on it in the same way with table. View is dynamic so it is not related to the physical schema and it is only stored as view definition. When the tables which are the source data of a view changes; the data in the view change also. (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/introduction-sql-views.aspx)

Here is a [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) to a reference on creating views.
Here is one more [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'view'?

Comment: A view is a customizable interface for a table or set of table.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(database)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: I think I understand views now. But using one table would result in the presence of several `null` values...

Comment: True, but if you only accessed the tables via the view, then you would not notice them.  What would be the issue with having nulls there?

Comment: @lansinwd: No, I was just concerned about memory, that's all.